# Error php artisan server (centOS 7+nginx1.14+php7.2+mariadb1.02 vía SCL)

Tags: laravel, php7, nginx, centos7

Estoy intentando aprender `laravel`, al ejecutar `"php artisan serve"` dentro del proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

> PHP Warning: require(/home/jairo/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/jairo/proyecto/artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error: require():
>   Failed opening required '/home/jairo/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/jairo/proyecto/artisan on line 18

El servidor de pruebas lo instalé en centos `7` vía `SLC` para tener la versión algo más reciente de `nginx1.14`, `php7.2` y `mariadb1.02` usando este tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-lemp-stack-software-collections-centos-7

Answer (score 0):

Este error es típico cuando no se han instalado las dependencias, por favor ejecuta desde la línea de comandos:

```
composer install
```

Comment: sí, ya lo hice, también composer update, ahora estoy probando remover composer y reinstalarlo de esta forma

Comment: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
 sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer